# How do you make an invisible button that works

Tags: android, kotlin, button

So I want to create an invisible button, but when I try to do that button becomes invisible but it doesn't works at all. How can I make it so that it's invisible but still working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you show use `transparent` color for the background and remove the text, here is the XML:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

and java code if you want to do it dynamically:

```
buttonVariable.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly leave it "visible", but color it the same as the background.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use it dynamically

button.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

It will work definitely

Answer (score 1):

Simply set background color to transparent. the button will not be visible but will work for sure.